# Pull data into Elastic Stack on Azure from Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

*Note: I am a beginner when it comes to Elastic.*

I have data on-prem that I pushed to an Azure Data Lake Gen 2. Since then, I created an Elastic Stack running on Azure in a self-managed manner, and I am looking to index and "use" the data that I have in the Data Lake. I cannot find connectors or any integration that would tackle this.

Is there a way to pull data into Elastic from an ADLS Gen 2 or a Storage Account?